# how to do validation for extra field added in user model for devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have searched for this question but not found an answer.

I am using devise for creating new user.
When i am creating a new user i have some fields which are required.

I have made entry of these fields also in user model like -

```
validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :company
```

I have  write in user model for validate presence of these fields, but devise is only considering validation for email field and not for other fields when i,m trying to create a new user.

I have also tried removing :validatable from user model and writing customized error validation but this also not working.

However i want to validate all require fields when i am creating a new user.

How to do this.

Thanks in advance??

Comment: Adding custom validation should work as expected. Also leave the `:validatable` call in place, or you'll have to add validations for email and password fields for yourself. How are your testing your changes? If it's in the `rails console`, you might just need to reload your code to pick up your additional validations.

Comment: @ Thomas Klemm: Thanks. That i obsevred and :validatable method is again applied in user model.

Comment: However remaining fields are not validating using devise when i'm creating a new user. i am getting error only for email field not for other fields. But this same is working when i'm editing profile of already created users, here error validation is working. I am not getting why it is not working when i'm creating a new user. any idea?

Comment: Does any one else knows why dis is happening..???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model add

```
validates :first_name, presence: true
validates :last_name, presence: true
```

Answer (score 0):

something give like this..

this is rails 3.2 validation, let me know what is your rails version

validates :first_name,:last_name, :presence=> { :message => "Field is required" }, :on => :create